# Android : how to set context to a view in layout xml?

Tags: android, layout, webview, android-context

I am using WebView in an ActivityGroup and it will throw an exception if WebView show Dialog and complain the activity is not valid. But it's okay if I set the context of the WebView to the TOP activity. So I wish to know how to set the context in the layout xml ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use layoutinflater to achieve this:

```
View viewToLoad = LayoutInflater.from(this.getParent()).inflate(R.layout.yourLayoutName, null);
this.theSpinner = (Spinner) viewToLoad.findViewById(R.id.Spinny);
this.setContentView(viewToLoad );
```

Hope that helps. for dialog you can just change context from **this** to

```
this.getParent()
```

Answer (score 0):

> > So I wish to know how to set the context in the layout xml ?

That's not possible. Though, I have some experience with `ActivityGroup`, so I know how to solve this problem:

```
// in your ActivityGroup...
public class YourActivityGroup extends ActivityGroup{
    public static YourActivityGroup self;
    public YourActivityGroup(){
        self = this;
        // the rest of your code here
    }
}
```

Then, when you need a context in order to show a dialog or a Toast or whatever, you use `YourActivityGroup.self`.

Comment: But if I get my Spinner with findViewById(...), I can't set the context - how can I achieve that? In combination with ActivityGroup, the spinner doesn't work, unfortunately...

Comment: I don't know why you would want to set the context to the spinner... is it giving you problems?

Comment: yes - it asks me if my activity is running: "Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@44ed8338 is not valid; is your activity running?"